# Calibration of a few binary classifiers is not perfect - why?

Tags: probability, classification, boosting, calibration

I am working on a binary classifier using LightGBM. I try to see the results of the classifiers when changing the costs of false positives and false negatives, still working on the same training and validating datasets. The objective function is defined as following:

```py
def my_scorer(y_true, y_pred):
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
    
    model_gain = loss * tp - gain * fp
    max_gain = loss * (fn + tp)
    
    return model_gain / max_gain

def lgbm_scorer(labels, preds):
    return 'lgbm_scorer', scorer_collection(labels, (preds > 0.5)), True
```

As I want to have probabilities as a result of my modelling, I use [isotonic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) as a final part of the pipeline.

```py
# sklearn version, for the sake of calibration
bst_ = LGBMClassifier(**search_params, **static_params, n_estimators = 1500)

bst_.fit(X = X_train, y = y_train, sample_weight = TRAIN_WEIGHTS,
         eval_set = (X_test, y_test), eval_sample_weight = [TEST_WEIGHTS],
         eval_metric = lgbm_scorer,
         early_stopping_rounds = 150, 
         callbacks = [lgb.reset_parameter(learning_rate = lambda current_round: learning_rate_decay(current_round, 
                                                                                                    base_learning_rate = learning_rate,
                                                                                                    decay_power = decay_power))],
         categorical_feature = cat_vars)

# Calibrate 
calibrated_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(
    base_estimator=bst_,
    method = 'isotonic',
    cv="prefit"
)
calibrated_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

`search_params` are hyperparameters defined individually (one set per model) using Optuna so that the ROC-AUC score is approx. the same for all the models, so that they are comparable.

By only changing variables of customized objective function (`loss` and `gain`), I can see that most of the classifiers are perfectly calibrated, but just a few are not - all of those few are below the 'perfectly calibrated' line.

Why has that happened? How come the calibration cannot be perfect - overall and in this scenario?

Comment: Why would you assume from the method to always give perfect results..?

Comment: As explained in the post, I got a perfect calibration for almost all of the combinations apart from a few, hence my question.

Comment: If you tossed coin 10 times and got 8 heads, would you ask why not 10? Algorithms like the one above don’t always give perfect results. No machine learning algorithm does that.

Comment: Providing some of the plots/scores, or ideally some code and sample data, would be very helpful in diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger thought that keeping it short and simple for discussing only the theory would be a good idea. Added some code to make my problem more clear.

Comment: And thanks for your feedback @Tim, it's not really helpful though, but thanks for trying :)

Comment: Can you add a couple of the calibration plots?  You've trained the isotonic regression on the same dataset as the main model, which is a no-no (see second paragraph [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html#calibrating-a-classifier)), but it's not clear to me if that would lead to disparate calibration results across models?  I suppose perhaps more-overfit models could see worsened calibrating functions?

Comment: You're totally right, I shouldn't have done the calibration in this way. It basically confirms that instead of asking why is this not perfect, I should be asking how to do calibration with LGBM .fit, as that's why I did calibration using `cv="prefit"`.

However, regarding your last question - I also tried to make sure that the scale of overfitting is almost the same. For all the models the ratio between `my_scorer` for training and testing datasets is 1.06-1.05. Not sure myself if it's high or not, but this is the best that I could do. So all the models overfit the same.

Answer (score 3):

Probably those models rank-order the samples poorly; since isotonic regression transforms the scores monotonically, it cannot fix the issue of score-bins having actual rates out of order.  To check that, compare the area under their ROC curves (since it depends only on the rank-ordering).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, roc curve is probably different for those that are not as well calibrated - hence if optimized the hyperparameters so that the ROC AUC is the same, then the calibration should be fixed as well?

Comment: Your update (that AUCs are similar) seems to invalidate this answer.  I'll leave it as a general answer, but ...

Answer (score 3):

The approach you are using is inconsistent with optimum decision making.  Don't use a "classifier" but instead estimate the probability of the outcome as a function of the predictors.  Then when making the ultimate decision you apply utilities/costs/losses to the consequences of all possible decisions to make the decision that maximizes expected utility.  Note that in the optimum Bayes decision the utilities are applied at the end, and are not part of the estimation process.  See Chapter 19 of [BBR](https://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf) for more information.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're suggesting is:

1. define a classifier which maximizes e.g. ROC AUC score,

2. define a logistic regression model which optimizes the customized objective function, and which takes the same variables as the one before AND the score from the previous classifier.

Is that correct?

Comment: No, no, no. First of all, don't use language 'develop a classifier' when you are not developing a classifier but are fitting a probability model (the likes of which is necessry for ROC calculation).   Second, AUROC is not a gold standard objective criterion.   Use the likelihood, penalized likelihood, or a Bayesian approach.  Then either avoid making a decision (i.e., make only a prediction) or ascertain the utilities needed to translate the predictions into optimum decision.